# Wordpress - Import custom CSV file in Database and validate upon registration

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, plugins, user-registration

I am trying to import custom CSV file in WP Database containing information about `product_type` and its `product_serial` number like below format. Plugins tried so far are [1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/), [2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer/) and [3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/)

```
product_type    product_serial
Apparel         app-192-168-1-1 
Cosmetic        cos-192-168-1-2
Footwear        foot-192-168-1-3
```

The plugins mostly imports `POSTS` data while I need to import custom data from CSV in my custom table `wp_product_details`

Later, on registration page, how can I fetch all `Product Serial #` from imported CSV and check if it matches user input ?

At the time of registration user needs to enter `Product Serial #` and if that number exists in that CSV list, only then registration is successful else it would validate user.

Any plugin that helps importing custom data apart from POSTS would work.

Comment: kind of custom work, plugins wont do your job.

Comment: @GopalSRathore, feasible approach to address the same ?

Comment: simplest approach would be like, .. provide a page for importing csv in admin section.  Next step, check with a query at the time of registration form submission ... if code exists.

Comment: Agree, can check query at the time of registration but being a newbie to  WP, how can I provide a page in admin for importing csv ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page